# How to safely store secrets / API keys in a CRA & express project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

Is it safe to have express server code and API keys in CRA project root directory and serve the build folder statically?

During the build process, does CRA copy or include content from any other files or directories except `/public` and `src` ? For example, in this process:

```
> npx create-react-app react-app
> cd react-app
> npm install
> npm install express
```

And then create `react-app/server.js` and `react-app/config.js` - and include API keys in config.js , `server.js` will serve frontend static files from the `react-app/build/` directory.

Will any content from `react-app/config.js` be included in `react-app/build/` directory after the build process? How safe it is to have server code and API secrets (.gitignored ofcourse) in a CRA project's root directory?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not safe to store anything vulnerable on the frontend side, all secret information should remain on the dedicated backend or env-variables stored in CI/CD and inject during deployment to your variables/placeholders.

If you are able to hide your backend from publicity - you are on a good track.